# Exception when trying to refresh Clojure code in cider

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I am using clojure in Emacs with cider and the cider repl (0.7.0). This is pretty fine, but whenever I run `cider-referesh` (or hit `C-c C-x`), I get an exception:

```
ClassNotFoundException clojure.tools.namespace.repl  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:372)

1. Unhandled java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
   clojure.tools.namespace.repl

           URLClassLoader.java:  372  java.net.URLClassLoader$1/run
           URLClassLoader.java:  361  java.net.URLClassLoader$1/run
         AccessController.java:   -2  java.security.AccessController/doPrivileged
           URLClassLoader.java:  360  java.net.URLClassLoader/findClass
       DynamicClassLoader.java:   61  clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader/findClass
              ClassLoader.java:  424  java.lang.ClassLoader/loadClass
              ClassLoader.java:  357  java.lang.ClassLoader/loadClass
                    Class.java:   -2  java.lang.Class/forName0
                    Class.java:  340  java.lang.Class/forName
                       RT.java: 2065  clojure.lang.RT/classForName
                 Compiler.java:  978  clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr/maybeClass
                 Compiler.java:  756  clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr/access$400
                 Compiler.java: 6583  clojure.lang.Compiler/macroexpand1
                 Compiler.java: 6613  clojure.lang.Compiler/macroexpand
                 Compiler.java: 6687  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                 Compiler.java: 6666  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                      core.clj: 2927  clojure.core/eval
                      main.clj:  239  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                      main.clj:  239  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                      main.clj:  257  clojure.main/repl/fn
                      main.clj:  257  clojure.main/repl
                   RestFn.java: 1096  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
        interruptible_eval.clj:   56  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate/fn
                      AFn.java:  152  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
                      AFn.java:  144  clojure.lang.AFn/applyTo
                      core.clj:  624  clojure.core/apply
                      core.clj: 1862  clojure.core/with-bindings*
                   RestFn.java:  425  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
        interruptible_eval.clj:   41  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
        interruptible_eval.clj:  171  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
                      core.clj: 2402  clojure.core/comp/fn
        interruptible_eval.clj:  138  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/run-next/fn
                      AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
       ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1142  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor/runWorker
       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:  617  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker/run
                   Thread.java:  745  java.lang.Thread/run
```

What is the reason for this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this exception was a bug, that has [now been fixed in cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/739).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.5"] to your project.clj

Comment: `cider-nrepl` already depends on it, so this should not be necessary unless @Ame is using `cider` without its middleware.

Comment: `lein deps :tree` will give you a list of the dependencies. Can you have a look to see what version of tools.namespace shows there?

Comment: I think I put it in the wrong place. I think it was supposed to go in `:plugins`, not `:dependencies`?